# Matrix Mirroring in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix of numbers:

```
[[a, b, c] 
 [d, e, f] 
 [g, h, i]]
```

that I would like to be mirrored accordingly:

```
[[g, h, i]
 [d, e, f]
 [a, b, c] 
 [d, e, f] 
 [g, h, i]]
```

And then again to yield:

```
[[i, h, g, h, i]
 [f, e, d, e, f]
 [c, b, a, b, c] 
 [f, e, d, e, f] 
 [i, h, g, h, i]]
```

I would like to stick to basic Python packages like numpy. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: There are many ways to do this, what did you try so far?

Comment: List comprehensions are your friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a simple helper function in pure python:

```
def mirror(seq):
    output = list(seq[::-1])
    output.extend(seq[1:])
    return output

inputs = [
   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   ['d', 'e', 'f'],
   ['g', 'h', 'i'],
]
print(mirror([mirror(sublist) for sublist in inputs]))
```

Obviously, once the mirrored list is created, you can use it to create a numpy array or whatever...

Answer (score 6):

Use `numpy.lib.pad` with `'reflect'`

```
m = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 
     ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
     ['g', 'h', 'i']]

n=np.lib.pad(m,((2,0),(2,0)),'reflect')

n
Out[8]: 
array([['i', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
       ['f', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
       ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['f', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
       ['i', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: See Numpy documentation on [np.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for `reflect` and `symmetric` and `wrap` and numerous other very interesting and useful modes!

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

X= [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]

A = np.asanyarray(X)
B= np.flipud(A)
C= np.concatenate((B, A[1:]), axis=0)
D = C[:,1:]
F = np.fliplr(C)
E = np.concatenate((F, D), axis=1)

print(E)
```

I have added step by step transformation. [flipud](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) and [flipud](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) refrence

output

```
[[9 8 7 8 9]
 [6 5 4 5 6]
 [3 2 1 2 3]
 [6 5 4 5 6]
 [9 8 7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged `numpy` so I'll assume your matrix is a 2d array

```
In [937]: A=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [938]: A
Out[938]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

flipping it on the rows:

```
In [939]: A[::-1,:]
Out[939]: 
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

concatenating vertically

```
In [940]: np.concatenate((A[::-1,:],A), axis=0)
Out[940]: 
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

removing the duplicate first line

```
In [941]: np.concatenate((A[::-1,:],A[1:,:]), axis=0)
Out[941]: 
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Do you think you can do the same with a horizontal (column) reversal and concatenate (axis=1)?

Answer (score 1):

And here is a non-numpy solution:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
b = list(reversed(a[1:])) + a # vertical mirror
c = list(zip(*b)) # transpose
d = list(reversed(c[1:])) + c # another vertical mirror
e = list(zip(*d)) # transpose again
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

```
from numpy import array, concatenate
m = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])
```

You can invert this along the first (vertical) axis via

```
>>> m[::-1, ...]
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

where `::-1` selects the rows from last to first in steps of `-1`.

To omit the last row, explicitly ask for the selection to stop immediately before `0`:

```
>>> m[:0:-1, ...]
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

This can then be concatenated along the first axis

```
p = concatenate([m[:0:-1, ...], m], axis=0)
```

to form:

```
>>> p
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

This can be repeated along the other axis too:

```
q = concatenate([p[..., :0:-1], p], axis=1)
```

yielding

```
>>> q
array([[9, 8, 7, 8, 9],
       [6, 5, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
       [6, 5, 4, 5, 6],
       [9, 8, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 
     ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
     ['g', 'h', 'i']]

m_m = [[m[abs(i)][abs(j)] 
      for j in range(-len(m)+1, len(m))] 
      for i in range(-len(m)+1, len(m))]
```

Or using numpy

```
m = array([['a', 'b', 'c'], 
           ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
           ['g', 'h', 'i']])

m_m = m.T[meshgrid(*2*[abs(arange(-len(m) + 1, len(m)))])]
```